# How to use TabHost with Intent in android studio

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-tabhost

I am learning android and i am using android studio ver1.4.1.
I wanna use a Tabhost that has two tabs and each tab content is a class with a layout. but each time i debug the program i got this message :Unfortunately, information has stopped. please help me.

mainActivity.xml:

```
<TabHost
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

mainActivity.java:

```
public class ActivityMain extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity_main);

    TabHost tabs = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setup();

    Intent intentPersonalInfo = new Intent().setClass(this,ActivityPersonalInfo.class);
    TabHost.TabSpec spec1 = tabs.newTabSpec("tag1");
    spec1.setContent(intentPersonalInfo).setIndicator("Personal Information");
    tabs.addTab(spec1);
}
```

seccondActivity.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

seccondActivity.java:

```
public class ActivityPersonalInfo extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(activity_personal_info);
}
```

manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.miad.information" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name=".ActivityMain" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ActivityPersonalInfo"></activity>
</application>
```